# how to install brew or homebrew on mac os 10.6

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have tried multiple times. Can anybody tell me exact detailed steps?
My mac os is 10.6.8.
It complains about some missing packages.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the error messages you get from your earlier install attempt, including the names of the packages it is missing.

Comment: I got it working now following command

/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"

I was running the

mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew

I have no idea what the two are doing though .

Comment: You should put that as an answer and accept it to help future people who come through with the same question. Also, ask a new question about why one works better than the other (although that question would be better-suited for Super User (superuser.com) or Ask Different (apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now following command `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL raw.github.com/gist/323731)"`.

I was running the `mkdir homebrew && curl -L github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew` I have no idea what the two are doing though

Comment: The raw.github.com link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 4):

Use this to install on Mac OSX 10.6.8

```
  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: Thank you. Ashish's link is returning error 400. But this worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open **terminal** (shortcut : `Press cmd + space` and enter `terminal` in `spotlight search)`
2. Enter command `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
3. Now you’ll be asked to **enter password** (note : passwords are not visible)

[image: Step 1]

4. If you get permission error as below

**fatal:** `cannot copy '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/pre-receive.sample'` `to` `'/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/hooks/pre-receive.sample':` **Permission denied**

```
Failed during: git init -q
```

5. Enter command `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`
6. Now you’ll be asked to enter password
7. Again enter the **same command written in step 2** (shortcut : simply *press top arrow button*)

[image: Step 2]

8. Wait patiently for sometime. You’ll see installation successful after a while.

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

9. Thereafter if you need any help regarding brew then simply enter `brew help` command. Refer this [link](https://brew.sh) for additional details.

[image: Step 5]

Answer (score 1):

[brew.sh](https://brew.sh) (the official home page) always has the most up-to-date installation instructions.

Comment: For getting and using a Github API token, see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130681/setting-github-api-token-for-homebrew

Answer (score 0):

```
This are my results on OSX 1068:

ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin10.0]

brew -v
Homebrew 1.3.4
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 897df; last commit 2017-10-06)
And after:
brew update
brew -v
Homebrew 1.3.5
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 713fe; last commit 2017-10-15)

 npm -v
5.4.2
and doing:
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
sudo npm i -g npm
npm -v
5.5.1

node -v
v6.9.5
And after:
brew upgrade node
```