# Setting Github API token for Homebrew

Tags: github, homebrew

You need to set `HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN` for [homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_management_software)) to avoid rate limiting, but how do you add it to homebrew config?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You create your API token on https://github.com/settings/tokens
and then set the environment variable `HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN` to the value of your token.

When creating the token, make sure that you only select the scopes you need. As pointed out in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32447595/133645) by Chad, **leaving all of the scopes unchecked is very reasonable!**

Setting the token is done using the `export` command. Example:

```
export HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN=xxxx
```

To make sure this is set whenever you open a terminal you can add this command to your `~/.brew_bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or any other file that is used during the initialisation of your shell file.

For future reference, this topic was discussed in the following two issues:

- https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/21023
- https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/21915

Comment: it makes me confusing a bit before I figure out the link to create Personal API Token is here https://github.com/settings/tokens not `https://github.com/settings/applications`

Comment: This post makes me a little uneasy because it's essentially telling users to put a password—which by default gives a lot more access than it needs to—in their login script. That's fine, but they should make sure they limit the scope of the token as mentioned by [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32447595/915501)

Comment: for those using zsh: just add or update the following entry in the `~/.zshrc` `HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN="your_new_token"`

Comment: Quoted or not? I am still getting an error when running this command: `brew gist-logs executable_name`.  "Error: Calling `brew gist-logs` with a password is disabled! Use HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN instead."

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer. In my homebrew installation, the token was saved in `.brew_bashrc`, so that's where I updated it.

Comment: If we don't want to keep the environmental variable in a dot file ( because we keep our dot files on GitHub ), then what other method can we use?

Answer (score 51):

Other than what @reto has already stated, it wasn't clear to me what scopes to select when creating a token. I was concerned about this, as I didn't want to allow too much.

According to https://gist.github.com/christopheranderton/8644743 they confirmed you *should* deselect all scopes. I've done this on my box and so far things work as expected.

Comment: This advice should really go into the selected answer in bold font.

Comment: The URL given by Homebrew when you encounter the rate limit error will have scopes deselected for you `https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=&description=Homebrew` but this answer was affirmation since Homebrew's output doesn't explicitly mention scopes.