# Homebrew: Fail to install homebrew on Mac OS X El Capitan(v10.11.1)

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

Yeah, I searched serveal same problem(like [how to install homebrew on MacOSx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381128/how-to-install-homebrew-on-os-x)) in StackOverflow, but problem still occurs:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com

The command I typed in the terminal comes from [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

> /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

But failed to install homebrew.

Comment: When you say 'failed to install homebrew', exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: just tell me:`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com`

Answer (score 0):

The El Capitan enabled System Integrity Protection (SIP) by default, to install homebrew,you have to disable it.

reboot your mac and when it is restarting, press 'command + r' to enter recovery mode.
open the Terminal and implement

```
csrutil disable
```

then reboot your mac and install the homebrew as you did.
when finishing installing homebrew, don't forget to enable SIP to protect your mac.

About SIP: [WWDC15 Security and Your Apps](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/706nu20qkag/706/706_security_and_your_apps.pdf)

Comment: thx, but I didn't try your way, and have installed homebrew successfully.

Comment: @triffic: so how did you do it then?!