# sudo brew doctor Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: python, homebrew, sudo, macos-sierra

I am trying to get pygame on my mac and so I am running through a step by step guide, to get the necessary items installed. I have installed `brew doctor`, but when I try to run the code: 
`sudo brew doctor`, I get an error shown below:

```
apples-MBP-2:~ MaxRothman$ sudo brew doctor
```

> Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer
>   supported. As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you
>   would be giving all build scripts full access to your system.

How can i get around this to carry on! Thanks

Comment: `Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported`.... Seems self explanatory

Comment: this might help: https://stdworkflow.com/386/mac-error-running-homebrew-as-root-is-extremely-dangerous-and-no-longer-supported#:~:text=Error%20message,the%20root%20user%20to%20install.

Answer (score 10):

As the error says:

> *Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and **no longer supported**.*

Run it without `sudo` as:

```
brew doctor
```

Also take a look at: [Viji's answer for installing doctor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357986/2063361)

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `sudo` when running brew doctor as brew in general modifies binaries in your /usr/ directories which when binaries are owned by root could cause issues later one.

Just run `brew doctor`