# How do I fix ImportError "Library not loaded" for pygame in alien invasion file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pygame

This is my code:

```py
import sys
import pygame

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game"""
        while True:
            # Watch for keyboard and mouse events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            # Make the most recently drawn screen visible
            pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance and run the game
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

I have installed pygame through the terminal on my mac.
When I tried to run my code, it gave me the error below.
I was expecting a blank screen.
I tried `pip uninstall pygame` and `pip install pygame`, but that did not work.
If somebody could help that would be great.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>  File "/Users/mycomputer/Desktop/python_work/alien_invasion.py", line 3, in <module>
>    import pygame
>
>  File "/Users/mycomputer/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 81, in  <module>
>
>    from pygame.base import * # pylint: disable=wildcard-import; lgtm[py/polluting-import]
> ```

> ```
> ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mycomputer/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Versions/A/Metal
>
>  Referenced from: /Users/mycomputer/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-39-darwin.so
>
>  Reason: image not found
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You do uninstall pygame with `pip` and `brew` and install pygame with `brew`

```
pip uninstall pygame
brew uninstall pygame
brew install pygame
```

Comment: I tried inputting those into terminal but it keeps saying -bash brew: command not found.

Comment: Follow this first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381128/installing-homebrew-on-os-x