How do I upgrade python on Mac?
I want to upgrade my version of python on Mac but I just can figure out how to do it.
Can I do:
pip3 install python3
or:
pip3 upgrade python3
or:
pip3 install python
or:
pip3 upgrade python3
I tried searching the web but no results worked for me.

You really should not upgrade binaries supplied by the OS. You can install a newer version of Python in addition to the one provided by the OS, and leave it alone. Just make sure the one you want to use is earlier in your PATH. Installing via Homebrew nicely takes care of the details for you. If you need to be able to switch between multiple Python versions, maybe look at pyenv

Do not mess with the builtin system version (2.7) of Python on MacOS (/usr/bin/python). Don't use it either - it's for internal use. Don't have /usr/bin near the front of your path, either. Install your own separate version/venv of Python.

To upgrade Python on your Mac, you should avoid using pip as it is a package manager for Python libraries, not for Python itself. Instead, you can download the latest version of Python from the official Python website and install it. Alternatively, if you have Homebrew installed, you can use the command brew upgrade python to update to the latest version of Python. Or opt for Anaconda which is a package and environment manager which you can set your python version in.

Do you how to install Homebrew?

Here's a link to the docs: https://docs.brew.sh/Installation. Otherwise I assume there will be youtube videos on it.

Here's another post about how to install brew. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381128/installing-homebrew-on-macos

The best way is to just download it from the website.
If you just want to update pip, you can use pip3 install --upgrade pip.
If you really want to use the CLI to update Python, make sure you have Homebrew installed and run brew install python. If you don't have Homebrew installed, first run /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)" then run the first command.

Consideration to take :
1.Are you working on just one programming project? use Homebrew.
2.Are you working on multiple programming projects? use Pyenv.
3.Before you upgrade Python on a Mac, check if Python is already installed, make sure you know how it was installed, and ask yourself if you need to use a different approach to installation based on the differences outlined above.
Installation process
1. Is Python installed?
You can check to see if your Mac has Python.
$ python --version
zsh: command not found: python
You'll see zsh: command not found: python if Python is not available, otherwise you will see a version number if install like :
$ python --version
Python 3.12.2
Note : The above checking of python version can still be typed in for the case of using the system Python(python3 --version,...)
1.Update Python installed with Homebrew
You can check if Python was installed with Homebrew. It will be listed among the Homebrew-installed packages:
$ brew list | grep python
python@3.12
This will show a Python version if it is installed via Homebrew. If you see zsh command not found brew, you don't have Homebrew.
$ which -a python (Shows the python location file)
/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/libexec/bin/python
You can upgrade a Python version with Homebrew(loosing access to old versions):
$ brew upgrade python
2.Update Python installed with Pyenv
If you have Homebrew installed, you can check if Pyenv is installed:
$ brew list | grep pyenv
pyenv
You can verify that Pyenv is installed by running:
$ pyenv --version
pyenv 2.4.0
Before you proceed, ensure that pyenv itself is up-to-date. If you installed pyenv via Homebrew, you can update it using the following command:
$ brew update && brew upgrade pyenv
Once you've decided on a version, you can install it using pyenv. For example, if you want to install Python 3.10.2, you would use the following command:
$ pyenv install 3.10.2
(Replace "3.10.2" with the version of Python you wish to install.)
After the installation is complete, you can set the newly installed Python version as the default version for your system using pyenv global. For example:
$ pyenv global 3.10.2
To verify that the new Python version is set correctly, you can use:
$ python --version
Or, specifically for pyenv, check the current version being used:
$ pyenv version

Which AI system did you use for this?

How do you install pyenv? I get this error when running pyenv --version: zsh: command not found: pyenv
